# How can I delay useEffect Hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect

I am using 2 useEffects on a file and the second useEffect is dependent on the first one.

Is there a way of delaying the second useEffect until the data from the first useEffect has been gotten?

```
const params = useParams()
const [userData, setUserData] = useState({})
const [followers, setFollowers] = useState([])

useEffect(() => getUser(params.id), [])

useEffect(() => {
    getFollowers(userData?.user?._id, auth.token)
}, [])

const getUser = async (id) => {
    const res = await getUserProfile(id)

    if (res) {
      setUserData(res)
    }
}


const getFollowers = async (id, token) => {
    const res = await getUserFollowers(id, token)
    if (res) {
      setFollowers(res)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Execute second `useEffect` only if first `useEffect` has retrieved its data:

```
const params = useParams()
const [userData, setUserData] = useState(null) // initialize userData as null
const [followers, setFollowers] = useState([])

useEffect(() => getUser(params.id), [])

useEffect(() => {
    // wait until userData is defined to make the second call
    if (userData)
        getFollowers(userData?.user?._id, auth.token)
}, [userData])
```

Answer (score 0):

Make one useEffect and make it async and fetch both API functions there with await.
Otherwise you also have a solution to add userData in 2nd useEffect as dependency which you can add in their dependency array.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to get followers any time `userData` changes, so make that a dependency of the effect:

```
useEffect(() => getUser(params.id), [])

useEffect(() => {
    const id = userData?.user?._id
    if (id) {
        getFollowers(id, auth.token)
    }
}, [userData?.user?._id]) // <=====
```

That will re-run the followers effect whenever that ID changes.

Alternatively,  you could combine them:

```
useEffect(() => {
    getUser(params.id), [])
    .then(userData => getFollowers(userData?.user?._id, auth.token))
    .catch(error => { /* ...handle/report error here...*/ })
}, []);

const getUser = async (id) => {
    const res = await getUserProfile(id)

    if (res) {
        setUserData(res)
    }

    return res // <==== Note returning the result as well as setting it
}

const getFollowers = async (id, token) => {
    const res = await getUserFollowers(id, token)
    if (res) {
        setFollowers(res)
    }
}
```

---

(In either case, the code should be handling rejeections from those `async` functions.)